# How does Download Management utilities control bandwidth usage?

Tags: networking, download-manager

I want to understand how utilities such as wget are able to rate-limit the download of a file by only consuming at most the provided rate.

Does it use QoS network features?
Or does it have a specific strategy for dealing with TCP sockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I want to understand how utilities such as wget are able to rate-limit

`wget` rate limits using the `--limit-rate` command line option:

- Wget implements the limiting by sleeping the appropriate amount of time after a network read that took less time than specified by the rate.
- Eventually this strategy causes the TCP transfer to slow down to approximately the specified rate.
- However, it may take some time for this balance to be achieved, so don’t be surprised if limiting the rate doesn’t work well with very small files.

---

#### --limit-rate=amount

> Limit the download speed to amount bytes per second. Amount may be
>   expressed in bytes, kilobytes with the `k` suffix, or megabytes with
>   the `m` suffix. For example, `--limit-rate=20k` will limit the
>   retrieval rate to 20KB/s. This is useful when, for whatever reason,
>   you don’t want Wget to consume the entire available bandwidth.
>
> This option allows the use of decimal numbers, usually in conjunction
>   with power suffixes; for example, `--limit-rate=2.5k` is a legal
>   value.
>
> Note that Wget implements the limiting by sleeping the appropriate
>   amount of time after a network read that took less time than specified
>   by the rate. Eventually this strategy causes the TCP transfer to slow
>   down to approximately the specified rate. However, it may take some
>   time for this balance to be achieved, so don’t be surprised if
>   limiting the rate doesn’t work well with very small files.

Source [GNU Wget 1.17.1 Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [Throttle the download speed of wget or curl while downloading](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39218/throttle-the-download-speed-of-wget-or-curl-while-downloading)